# django custom user's model and UserAdmin - Programmin error while adding a new user

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-authentication

I'm having some troubles while using a custom user model and the admin

```
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class Employee(AbstractUser):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Employee'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Employees'


# settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.Employee'


# admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from myapp.models import Employee


admin.site.register(Employee, UserAdmin)
```

Well when I try to add a new user, it trows me this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8050/admin/chaos/employee/add/

Django Version: 1.7.1
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
['admin_tools',
 'admin_tools.theming',
 'admin_tools.menu',
 'admin_tools.dashboard',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_extensions',
 'reversion',
 'mptt',
 'imperavi',
 'django_mptt_admin',
 'document',
 'chaos']
Installed Middleware:
['django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Traceback:
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  584.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  204.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  394.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/admin.py" in add_view
  121.                                                extra_context)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1454.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  394.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1397.             if form.is_valid():
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  162.         return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  154.             self.full_clean()
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  353.         self._clean_fields()
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_fields
  371.                     value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in clean_username
  101.             User._default_manager.get(username=username)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  92.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  351.         num = len(clone)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  122.         self._fetch_all()
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  966.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  265.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  700.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  786.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  81.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/chaos/employee/add/
Exception Value: relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
```

Anybody experienced the same thing and any hint to solve it?

I had a suspect that I need also to subclass the `UserCreationForm` and `UserChangeForm` used by the original UserAdmin, but if it is the correct way, I honestly don't see the advantages of using a custom user model rather that create a one-to-one model (e.g. `Profile`) to extend the original User.

Thanks
Luca

Answer (score -4):

Good day, Luke!

Please, look at django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/

Just check, what model you are using: CustomUser or Abstract**Base**User.
As I can see, now it's *AbstractUser*.

Comment: from django docs:
"If you’re entirely happy with Django’s User model and you just want to add some additional profile information, you could simply subclass django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser and add your custom profile fields, although we’d recommend a separate model as described in the “Model design considerations” note of Specifying a custom User model. AbstractUser provides the full implementation of the default User as an abstract model."
Anyway, solved specifying a proper custom manager for the custom user model.

Comment: Agree with that! My bad. Sorry. Anyway, in my case I prefer to use OneToOneField.